# Is allocation C memory to hold a Go struct a supported use case for cgo?

Tags: go, cgo

I've been exploring strategies around not passing nested go pointers around into C. Here's an example of how I'm try out allocating a block of C memory with the intent of holding a Go struct:

```
(*MyGoStruvt)(C.calloc(1, unsafe.Sizeof(MyGoStruvt{})))
```

Does anyone know if this is a supported use case? And if not, could someone explain how wrong this approach is?

Comment: Whether this is OK depends on what is inside the Go structure type.

Comment: The go runtime does not care what is written to C allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is simple: if you are allocating memory using malloc, calloc, etc, you are accepting C memory management policy. Golang runtime doesn't know anything about your allocations. So you have to be explicit and call free at some point. Otherwise it's a memory leak.